# Seems you're trying to access 'ReactNative.Component' from the 'react-native' package

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to learn react-native from Tyler McGinnis tutorial: https://egghead.io/lessons/react-react-native-basic-ios-routing#/tab-code

The error message below seems straight forward, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

> Seems you're trying to access 'ReactNative.Component' from the 'react-native' package. Perhaps your meant to access 'React.Component' from the 'react' package instead. For example instead of:
>
> import React, {Component,View} from 'react-native';
>
> You should now do:
>
> import React, {Component} from 'react';  import {View} from
>   'react-native';

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import {AppRegistry,NavigatorIOS,StyleSheet,Text,View} from 'react-native';

import {Main} from './App/Components/Main';

var styles = StyleSheet.create({   container: {
     flex: 1,
     backgroundColor: '#111111'   }, });
```

Comment: Could you post the rest of the file contents as well as the one from Main.js?

Comment: Thanks: https://github.com/ebruner/githubNotetaker/blob/master/index.ios.js   - https://github.com/ebruner/githubNotetaker/blob/master/App/Components/Main.js

Comment: Thanks, I've added my answer below.  You have a conflict because you use React.Component in Main where previously a variable `React` has been defined and assigned to the 'react-native' default export

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The cause of your error:

> Your file sets `React` to **'react-native'** default export and *not* **'react'** one. 
> Later in the file you are
>   Accessing `React.Component` on a variable that is set to the **'react-native'** default export won't work (React native doesn't contain `Component` as a named export)
> The **'react'** library is where the `{Component}` (and therefore `React.Component`) named export *is* defined.

---

**Solution:**

In *Main* change your imports to the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

...

class Main extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <Text>Testing the Router</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
};
```

When you refer to `React.Component` now, there is no issue because it has been defined properly whilst still retaining references to React-Native components.

Answer (score 2):

This error message was supposed to be a warning about a deprecation introduced with v 0.25.1

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.25.1

Requiring React API from react-native is now deprecated. You still have it in your Main.js

```
var React = require('react-native');

var {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} = React;
```

Change it to :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet,Text,View} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: The 'deprecation' you are referring to is not what is causing the error.  It is merely because a reference to React.Component was being used on React in the Main component which was defining a variable called `React` and setting it to the React-Native