# Why the component react-native-typewriter doesn't work?

Tags: react-native

I followed the istruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636758/seems-youre-trying-to-access-reactnative-component-from-the-react-native-pa), but it still doesn't work.

I am trying this external component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-typewriter

So, I have installed it with:

> npm install --save react-native-typewriter

and then I have wrote this code:

**index.android.js**

```
'use strict';

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import TypingText from './app/textanimation.js';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => TypingText );
```

**textanimation.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import TypeWriter from 'react-native-typewriter';

class TypingText extends Component {
  render() {
     return <TypeWriter typing={1}>Hello World!</TypeWriter>
  }
}

export default TypingText;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.41.2",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-typewriter": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "assets/fonts/04b03"
    ]
  }
}
```

But I get the error below:

> Seems you're trying to access 'ReactNative.Component' from the
>   'react-native' package. Perhaps you meant to access 'React.Component'
>   from the 'react' package instead?
>
> ```
> For example, instead of:
>
>   import React, { Component, View } from 'react-native';
>
> You should now do:
>
>   import React, { Component } from 'react';
>   import { View } from 'react-native';
>
> Check the release notes on how to upgrade your code - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.25.1
> ```

Comment: Hi, looking onto your code seems you have imported wrong component name. Instead of `TextAnimation` it should be `TypingText` in index.android.js

Comment: @NeelGala I still get the error.

Comment: your `textanimation.js` is totally right, check your `index.android.js` where you have imported on 2nd line `TextAnimation` it should be `TypingText`

Comment: @NeelGala done, but I still get the error.

Comment: is error still same ?

Comment: in `textanimation.js` instead of using `React.Component` use only `Component` and modify the import like this `import React, {Component} from 'react'`

Comment: Done, still the same error. Maybe the component is outdated ?

Comment: Is the error still same after modifying import?

Comment: @NeelGala yes it's the same

Comment: can you edit your code above

Comment: @NeelGala just edited :)

Comment: in index.android.js replace all `TypeWriter` with `TypingText`

Comment: @NeelGala done, still the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally got the solution on the issue of `react-native-typewriter` package.

Navigate to node_modules> react-native-typewriter> index.js 
Edit the following header from

```
import React, {
  Component,
  Text,
  PropTypes,
} from 'react'
```

**to**

```
import React, {
  Component,
  PropTypes,
} from 'react'

import {
  Text,
} from 'react-native'
```

Working short Example

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import{AppRegistry,} from 'react-native';
import TypeWriter from 'react-native-typewriter';
export default class HelloWorld extends Component{
    constructor(){
    super();
    }
    render() {
           return <TypeWriter typing={1}>Hello World!</TypeWriter>
        }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorld', () => HelloWorld);
```

Working Example for R-N 0.42.0

Comment: I have edited the code as you said, but I still get the error. I have also delete the app from the device and rebuilt it with react-native run-android.